# Replacing a material found on many objects to another material at once for all of those objects. Possible?

Tags: materials

Replacing a material found on many objects to another material at once for all of those objects.

Possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes

If you bring up the select linked menu (Shift-L) with one object that have the material of interest and then choose Material, then use the link menu (Ctrl-L) you can link material from the active object (last selected).

[image]

[image]

Comment: If you select an object and hit Shift+L you will select all the objects with the same material. (For first step)

Comment: Did I not get the question right?

Comment: They asked, how can change Material.001 to Material.002 on every object which has Material.001 so they has to select all of them first.

Comment: It was a bit ambiguous but I can see it now. Thanks... updated my answer